# Laravel groupby min/max filter grouped results

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I've got a Laravel query working the way I'd like with `min()` and `groupBy()`:

```
$certificates = CertificateRecord::whereHas('learner', function($query) use($user) { $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id); })
->selectRaw('*,min(type) as type')
->groupBy('certificate_template_id')
->with('issuer','certificateType')
->paginate(10);
```

But when I add this to the mix...

```
->when($request->type, function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('type', '=', $request->type);
})
```

The previously grouped results are somehow ignored while performing this `where()` and it returns all ungrouped rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The original query with the `when` condition placement here seems fine to me. This should filter the `type` field without affecting the groupBy. One thing i want to tell you is that when the `$request->type` is set, there would be only one `type` value in the result set, therefore the minimum  value would be the same without any change.

```
$certificates = CertificateRecord::whereHas('learner', function($query) use($user) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
})
    ->with('issuer', 'certificateType')
    ->when($request->type, function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->where('type', $request->type);
    })
    ->selectRaw('*, min(type) as type')
    ->groupBy('certificate_template_id')
    ->paginate(10);
```

---

```
$certificates = CertificateRecord::whereHas('learner', function($query) use($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
    })
    ->with('issuer', 'certificateType')
    ->selectRaw('*, min(type) as type')
    ->groupBy('certificate_template_id')
    ->when($request->type, function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->having('type', '=', $request->type);
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```

If that doesn't work, switch having to havingRaw.

```
return $query->havingRaw('min(type) = ' . $request->type);
```

Comment: I'm getting:

`Unknown column 'type' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 'certificate_records' where exists (select * from 'learners' where 'certificate_records'.'learner_id' = 'learners'.'id' and 'user_id' = 3) group by 'certificate_template_id' having 'type' = 1)`

And

`Unknown column '1' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 'certificate_records' where exists (select * from 'learners' where 'certificate_records'.'learner_id' = 'learners'.'id' and 'user_id' = 3) group by 'certificate_template_id' having min(type) = 1)`

Comment: @jerfbillings i made an update to the answer, honestly the original query with the addition of when condition seems fine. It would be helpful if you could show us the result set with and without it and the value of request->type when used

Answer (score 0):

Just don't complete the query immediately:

```
$query = $certificates = CertificateRecord::whereHas('learner', function($query) use($user) { $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id); })
->selectRaw('*,min(type) as type')
->groupBy('certificate_template_id')
->orderBy('type')
->with('issuer','certificateType')

if ($request->status){ $query->where('status', '=', $request->status); }

$query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: But doing this seems to return all original results with that conditional, ignoring the grouping.